# Yoneda's lemma: group morphisms give Hopf-algebra morphisms

Tags: category-theory, duality-theorems, hopf-algebras, natural-transformations, representable-functor

Let $k$ be a commutative ring. Let $\text{Alg}$ be the category of commutative $k$-algebras and $\text{CHopf}$ the category of commutative Hopf-algebras. Let us also write $[\text{Alg}, \text{Grp}]$ for the category of representable functors $\text{Alg} \to \text{Grp}$ (the morphisms are natural transformations between such functors).

We have an obvious functor
$$\text{CHopf}^{op} \to [\text{Alg}, \text{Grp}]: H \mapsto \text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H,-)$$
since the sets $\text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H,A)$ obtain a group structure via convolution for every algebra $A$. Concretely, the multiplication is defined by
$$f \star g := \mu(f \otimes g)\Delta$$ where $\mu$ is the multiplication on $A$ and $\Delta$ is the comultiplication on $H$. On the level of morphisms, the above functor is defined using the Yoneda lemma.

I'm trying to show that this functor is fully faithful. For this, I need to show that if $\lambda: \text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H,-) \to \text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H',-)$ is a natural transformation that consists of group morphisms and where $H,H'$ are commutative Hopf-algebras, then the morphism
$$\lambda_H(\text{id}_H) \in \text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H',H)$$
is a Hopf-algebra morphism. In particular, I try to check that
$$(\lambda_H(\text{id}_H) \otimes \lambda_H(\text{id}_H))\Delta_{H'}= \Delta_H \lambda_H(\text{id}_H).$$

First of all, is this true? If it is true, how can I show it? I have tried to exploit the fact that $\lambda_H$ is a group morphism but could not conclude.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the specifics regarding Hopf algebras, but shouldn't a simple categorical argument showing both sides are the same after applying $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively (where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the standard projection morphisms $H \times H \to H$ on the first and second factor) do the trick?

Comment: @Rushy I don't quite see how that works. Can you maybe elaborate?

Comment: Ah sorry, I spoke a bit too soon, I forgot for a moment the tensor product is a coproduct so that approach doesn't work. I'm not quite sure how to show it then

Comment: @Rushy No worries, I'm not sure either ;)

Comment: Isn't this a general fact about group objects? See for instance the stuff at the end of https://math.fontein.de/2009/08/16/fun-with-representable-functors-or-why-i-like-yondeas-lemma/  .  You can apply this in the category of affine group schemes rather than Hopf algebras in order to only deal with group objects rather than co-group objects.

Comment: @babu_babu I'm not too familiar with the language used there. If you want, you can try to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that $\lambda$ preserves the group structure is equivalent to saying that, for any $A \in \text{Alg}$, the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H \otimes_{k} H, A) @>{- \circ \Delta_{H}}>> \text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H,A) \\
@V{- \circ (\lambda_{H}(\text{id}_{H}) \otimes \lambda_{H}(\text{id}_{H}))}VV @VV{- \circ \lambda_{H}(\text{id}_{H})}V\\
\text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H' \otimes_{k} H' ,A) @>>{- \circ \Delta_{H'}}> \text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H',A)
\end{CD} commutes ("$- \circ f$" means "precomposition by $f$"). Take $A := H \otimes_{k} H$ above, and consider the image of $\text{id}_{H \otimes_{k} H} \in \text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H \otimes_{k} H,H \otimes_{k} H)$ in $\text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(H',H \otimes_{k} H)$; via the bottom-left corner, the image is $(\lambda_{H}(\text{id}_{H}) \otimes \lambda_{H}(\text{id}_{H})) \circ \Delta_{H'}$, and via the top-right corner, the image is $\Delta_{H} \circ \lambda_{H}(\text{id}_{H})$.